# How to access function from parent component when in modal component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

The `refreshTable()` function is in the parent component. I need to trigger it whenever I updated information in my modal and closes it.

I am using *@ng-bootstrap* for my modal

For may **parent.component.ts**

> ```
> import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
>
>  constructor(
> private ngbModal: NgbModal,
> )
>
> viewModal() {
>     const openModal = this.ngbModal.open(ModalComponent);
>     openModal .componentInstance.id = row.id;
> }
>
> refreshTable() {
>     //refresh code block here
> }
> ```

For my modal.component.ts

> ```
> import { NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
>
> constructor(
> private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
> )
>
> updateParent() {
>     //update data to database code here
>     this.activeModal.close();
> }
> ```

How to trigger `refreshTable()` from ModalComponent after closing the modal? Since there are changes in the data from database, data from parent is not updated accordingly when modal is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to this

```
const openModal = this.ngbModal.open(ModalComponent);
openModal.componentInstance.id = row.id;
openModal.dismissed.subscribe(
  _ => {
    this.refreshTable();
  }
)
```

in `parent.component.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Pass it from the parent component to the child component as a prop.

Use `bind` or an arrow function to preserve the `this` value.

Answer (score 0):

Add an output event to your modal component

```
@Output() onCLose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

When the user clicks close just call the `emit()` method

```
this.onCLose.emit(value); //value can be whatever you want to pass to the parent
```

Update your `viewModal` method in the parent to include a subscription to the close event

```
viewModal() {
   const openModal = this.ngbModal.open(ModalComponent);
   openModal.componentInstance.id = row.id;
   openModal.componentInstance.onClose.subscribe(value => 
      // handle the close event
      this.refreshTable();
   })
}
```

You could also do it any other way communication between components can be achieved:

- service
- state management (ngrx, etc)

Answer (score 0):

ngBootstrap modals have a `beforeDismiss` event, to which you can add logic before you close the modal. You have to return a truthy value for the modal to actually close.

You could do it like this:

```
const openModal = this.ngbModal.open(ModalComponent, { beforeDismiss: () => this.updateParent() }); // if modal is not closing, your function is returning false.
```

Check [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api) for info on that function (do use ctrl F to find the option if needeD)

Edit: @tom-fong's answer is also a good solution, but you'd have to check if you're using version > 8.0.0